# Tcp connection leak issue

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, connection-leaks

Observed an issue in which system is throwing - "too many open files" after working fine for few hours.  
Observed that there are many tcp connection stuck in "CLOSE_WAIT" state. 
**sudo lsof | grep ":http (CLOSE_WAIT)" | wc -l** -> **16215.** 
Number is increasing with time and in few hours it would cross max limit allowed.

Also ran netstat command - 
 "**netstat -ant | awk '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n**"  and output is -> **122** CLOSE_WAIT.

1. Why output from netstat command is way lower than lsof command. Both are returning close wait connections and should have given approx same value.
2. Once i got to know that connection to specific service is causing this issue, then what should i do identify the exact code where this is happening ? I went through the client code for connecting to service and i don't see any connection leakage.

Comment: Did you ever learn what caused this?